# XSLT Processor (from XML to HTML) on React Native

Tags: javascript, xml, react-native, xslt, javascriptcore

I have the following data input:

1. a XML string
2. a XSLT string

The goal is to render the output HTML (output of the XSLT processing on the XML data) on the React Native (i.e., on the webview, integrated browser, etc. is not important where, I have just give the possibility to read the output).

The problem is that javascript core doesn't provide API such as XSLTProcessor() for solving this requirementes. I tried also the [https://github.com/fiduswriter/xslt-processor][https://github.com/fiduswriter/xslt-processor] project but I receive an error on the "decimal-format" support.

BTW, I tried to show data my desktop browsers and It works, so input I have is good.

Comment: Once Saxon-JS 2 from Saxonica arrives, it might be able to serve as a Javascript library for XSLT transformation outside the context of a browser, like Node.js or perhaps javascriptcore too. But I don't know how Saxonica is going to license it.

Comment: I tried also the Saxon-JS 1.2 but it doesn't work with javascript core (due to dependencies missing)